# how to change the src attribute getting data from text box in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that consists a text input with ID="text" and a button with ID="button".
and also I have a link that has a src attribute.
would you give me some jQuery code that when I write something in text input area and then by clicking on the button, the Src of the a tag changes to what I wrote in text input?

Comment: Try google and be a little more enthusiastic....SO is to help u fix errors, it is not a coding machine.

Comment: jQuery is quite easy to learn. I recommend looking at their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). People are not trying to mean, they just expect you to try it on your own rather than asking for someone else to write your code for you. If you have trouble after making a legitimate effort, tell us about your effort and where you're having issues. People will be more likely to help then.

Comment: I think because I requested directly to give me the code you're not interested to awnser me and you think that I didn't google, but I did but because I'm newbie in jQuery I couldn't understand how to use them to reach what I want, for example I searched and in w3schools in .attr method, the example was assigning a static and pre-defined link to src attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set  but I want to do it dynamic that when the textbox changes the src attribute changes too.

Comment: This is my code, It's vivid that It's wrong but I write it here that you can awnser me better: 

$(document).ready(function(){
var val1 = $('#text').val()
$('#button').click(function(){
$('#atag').attr("src" ,  attr( "id", "val1")
});
});

Answer (score 0):

```
If(user == numbnut | user == lazy)
{ response.write("GFGI" + " AND TRY SOME STUFF!";
}
else{ /* user has tried to figure it out and posts indications of code written and tried
debug(user_submitted_code);
}
```

That's how you'd write it in c#, but it should be easy to convert to JS.